# Using external VPN resources from inside VirtualBox

Tags: openvpn

I'm using NetworkManager to connect to work via OpenVPN. It works nicely, but VirtualBox guests (connected to the host with NAT) can't resolve work-related hostnames.

The OpenVPN server pushes a "dhcp-option DNS" to the client, so the host CAN resolve those hostnames, but it looks like the guest cannot... Is this expected? Am I missing something?

(Both host and guest are Xubuntu Lucid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to connect at all to any vpn-IP?
First try to ping one of those IPs.
If that's successful and you're unable to ping a vpn-hostname then you are facing a DNS problem.

What works for me is having the virtualbox network adapter set to Bridged and the interface set to the vpn (tap0 in my case).
By the way, since the mode is bridged, if you're having a network issue on the guest it's very likely you're also having it on the host.

Comment: Ping works, but the pulldown doesn't show the VPN interface (tun0)... Anyway I noticed that if I reboot the VM while the VPN is up, the DNS *does* work, while if I just reconnect eth0 it doesn't... Strange! Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: Well the interface is one thing but you also have the possibility to choose the adapter type namely NAT or Bridge, etc. You can try changing it to Bridged.
And yes I would always first start the vpn and then boot the VM.

Comment: I have it set to a bridged adapter but there is no tap0 option in the dropdown. It doesn't seem to work. I can't ping any ip address on the network.